# Where do you get bombs from in Super Adventure Box?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have seen several obvious looking destructible walls in Super Adventure Box, but have not been able to find a way to destroy them.

Considering the Zelda influences, are there bombs available to destroy the walls?
How do I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mini bombs can be bought for 200 baubles from the shop in area 2 of World 1 Zone 2 or from any shop in World 1 Zone 3.

What you actually get is a bundle skill, that changes your skillset to let you throw bombs. Each bomb you throw costs 1 bauble.

Comment: Ah, cool... that seems expensive... shouldn't have bought that shovel first :)

Comment: It's okay! If you are not adverse to a bit of popping in and out of instances, there a spot in World 1 Zone 2 that constantly pops (via the shovel) 40 baubles once every instance.

Comment: I was actually getting pissed about the achievement, thinking every bomb would cost 200g. Thank you for making my day!